# Host page from github

Tags: github, github-pages

I am trying to host a web page from github. Namely, I am trying to do that with the page: https://github.com/oobarbazanoo/JS-BuyList.
I type to the address bar oobarbazanoo.github.io/JS-BuyList and nothing happens I just get an error.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The GitHub Pages branch is called `gh-pages` by default. Have you changed it to master? (It’s in the Settings tab.)

Comment: @Ryan, Thanks a lot. Right settings helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to solve the problem follow these steps:

> 1. Go to you Repository.
> 2. At the top choose Settings.
> 3. Go to the GitHub Pages.
> 4. Choose the source you need and save it.
> 5. Wait a few minutes, then copy and paste web link which will be given in GitHub Pages section.